# How I can make call back from EpoxyModel?

Tags: java, android, epoxy

I need to make call back from MyEpoxyModel. 
I need call callback in Controller from Model
How I can do it ? (with epoxy)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass anything from an adapter to your EpoxyModel. For example, if you want to pass a callback listener, use

```
    @CallbackProp
    fun setClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener?) {
        setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
    }
```